how to inject alan-ai/alan-sdk-web in my react app?
how to inject alan-ai/alan-sdk-web in my react app so that i can easily embed AI Voice Assistant in my React app?
i have tried:
npm i @alan-ai/alan-sdk-web @material-ui/core classnames words-to-numbers

but this command is not working in the react app directory. it is only working out of the directory

Not sure what's the exact error you have with Alan! But consider checking this easier AI Voice Assistant for React, it works in all my Next & React projects  https://github.com/sista-ai/ai-assistant-react
